# CompositeData has no keys() method?

Tags: java, jmx, diagnostics, jconsole

I'm using JMX to save some diagnostic information from a remote process. Looking at the interface in jconsole shows that the return type is [CompositeData](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/CompositeData.html) (the data actually comes back as [CompositeDataSupport](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/CompositeDataSupport.html)). I want to output all the key/value pairs that are associated with this object.

The problem is that the interface just seems to have a "values()" method with no way of getting the keys. Am I missing something here? Is there some other way to approach this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you could do

```
Set< String > keys = cData.getCompositeType().keySet();
```

(given that cData is a CompositeData object)

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/CompositeType.html#keySet()

Answer (score 2):

You can find a more complete example with this [small program that prints the attributes of all JVM MBeans](http://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/a_small_program_that_prints)

In particular:

```
StringBuffer writeCompositeData(StringBuffer buffer, 
            String prefix, String name, CompositeData data) {
        if (data == null)
            return writeSimple(buffer,prefix,name,null,true);
        writeSimple(buffer,prefix,name,"CompositeData("+
                data.getCompositeType().getTypeName()+")",true);
        buffer.append(prefix).append("{").append("\n");
        final String fieldprefix = prefix + " ";
        for (String key : data.getCompositeType().keySet()) {
            write(buffer,fieldprefix,name+"."+key,data.get(key));
        }
        buffer.append(prefix).append("}").append("\n");
        return buffer;
    }
```

The part:

```
for (String key : data.getCompositeType().keySet()) {
    [...] data.get(key) [...];
}
```

being what you are after.